# Clang, how do these types conflict?

Tags: c, clang, cpython

Trying to compile the Python interpreter with clang (on Windows), I'm getting (after some refinement):

```
c:\Python-3.10.4\Python\pytime.c:603:5: error: conflicting types for '_PyTime_AsTimeval'
int _PyTime_AsTimeval(_PyTime_t t, struct timeval *tv, _PyTime_round_t round)
    ^
C:\Python-3.10.4\Include/cpython/pytime.h:126:5: note: previous declaration is here
int _PyTime_AsTimeval(_PyTime_t t, struct timeval *tv, _PyTime_round_t round);
    ^
```

Um... those don't look conflicting to me! What am I missing? Does the Python code do something unusual with these declarations? Is there a way to get clang to give more information about the conflict it sees? (The Microsoft compiler accepted this code with no complaint.)

Comment: Why does the 2nd header file have slashes for some of it's path separators?

Comment: @AllanWind Because #include directives use them. That's always the case, regardless of operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! The problem is that `struct timeval` was not yet declared by the time the function declarations were read. Microsoft C takes that as meaning 'global declaration of the struct will be forthcoming'; clang takes it as 'make a temporary declaration, then discard it, so that the function prototype is incompatible with later definition'.

```
void square(struct foo *f);

struct foo {
  int x;
};

void square(struct foo *f) {}
```

And can be patched in `pytime.h` by inserting this before the function prototypes:

```
struct timeval;
```

I don't know which if either behavior is more consistent with the wording of the standard, but have reported it as a bug in clang anyway, on the theory that behaving the same way as the Microsoft compiler would be the more useful behavior.